# how do we call restful webservice post()method from ui

Tags: web-services, rest

I am very  new to restful webservices. I need to call a restful webservice `post()` method from
my application Form.

How do we call restful webservice `post()` method from user Interface.?

Comment: <form method="POST"> or use Ajax. Jquey may help

Comment: You need to provide more information. From what "UI" are you trying to call the web service? A web application? C#? Java? For that matter, have you tried google: "<programming language you're using> call web service" ?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use [`ajax`](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/). Read more about it.

Comment: And if the client isn't written in javascript?